# Why is my FPS Camera in the Wrong Position by Default?

Tags: unreal-4, first-person-shooter

I'm using Unreal 4.2, and somewhere a long time ago I must have messed up settings.  I'm trying to mess with a first person shooter, so I create a new project, using the first person template.  When it opens, this is what my character looks like in the viewport.[image]
When I play the game, it looks like this.[image] Clearly the camera position is messed up or something, because I know it's not supposed to show that much of the characters arms, and it looks wrong.  How do i reset the settings, or fix this?  I'm not even sure how i accomplished this. It does this every time I make a project with this template.  Thanks.

Comment: This looks correct to me, similar to a view over your shoulder in real life. If you're not content, move the camera up a bit and narrow the view to 45° or so. But others playing the game will probably object then, that the view is "unnatural" :-)

Comment: thanks for the comment.  I think I pretty much fixed it by changing the cameras fov, but not sure enough to answer yet.  :)  Actually, I haven't seen many views like this, most fps I've seen (not that I've seen that many) only show the gun and a little of the hands.